# Просмотр подтаблицы Access через sql - запрос в c#

Tags: c#

Добрый вечер. Как прочитать данные из подтаблицы на языке c# при помощи sql-запроса. Таблицы находятся в СУБД Access.Из связи видно, что мне нужно получить доступ к данным из таблицы Witnesses 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0MdK.jpg

Comment: В access можно отобразить связи между таблицами. Вы скриншот этой схемы добавьте в свой вопрос, а также назовите те таблицы кои вы считаете `подтаблица`ми, чтоб прояснить окончательно свой вопрос.

Comment: @Bulson, я знаю, как прочитать данные из таблицы Base, а из её подталиблицы Witnesses - нет